# Is there any better gui for managing network?

Tags: raspbian, dhcp, gui, networkmanager

I'd like to have some better gui for managing network connections, something similar to `nm-connection-editor`. But `nm-connection-editor` is available for `NetworkManager` and I want more advanced gui for `dhcpcd`.

> UPDATE
>
> ↓

@Andyroo advised to add some details.
Here they are: possibility of setting static IP, netmask, default gateway etc. for multiple network interfaces, possibility of setting VPN. So these are actually functionalities just like in `nm-connection-editor`. Of course I'm looking for gui for managing `dhcpcd` on Raspbian.

Answer (score 1):

[Roy Marples](https://roy.marples.name/about/) maintains the dhcpcd network package and the dhcpcd-ui for config - details are [here on his site](https://roy.marples.name/projects/dhcpcd-ui/). Maybe asking on the mailing list could turn something up if you do not want to fork/edit the code yourself?

It may help others to edit your question to detail your needs a bit more (e.g. explain what you need it to do)?